# Excluding a specific URL from HTTP Basic Auth - mod_rewrite causing problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

We have "HTTP Basic Auth" on a certain subdomain of ours, but would like to allow everything to access a specific URL on that subdomain without authenticating (for a 3rd party hitting our webhook URL).

So I tried to use `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/webhook/ allow` to allow with `Allow from env=allow` (full file below) but it seems that because we've got some mod_rewrite rules to rewrite all these URLs to a PHP entry point, the Request_URI is never actually /webhook once it gets to this point (guessing but didn't know how to 100% confirm this.

It's still asking for a basic auth user/pass regardless of the URL.

**Note that the .htaccess file is the same on all our domains / subdomains, whereas the VirtualHost can be configured just for this subdomain.**

**Full VirtualHost config with the "HTTP Basic Auth" config section:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

  DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.ourdomain.co.uk/blah/www

  ServerAdmin x@ourdomain.co.uk
  ServerName sub.ourdomain.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.sub.ourdomain.co.uk

  ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
  ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 410 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 411 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 412 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 413 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 414 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 415 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 501 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 503 /error.php
  ErrorDocument 506 /error.php

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/sub.ourdomain.co.uk.apache.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/sub.ourdomain.co.uk.access.log combined

  <Directory "/var/www/sub.ourdomain.co.uk/blah/www">
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/webhook/ allow

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwords/sub.ourdomain.co.uk

    # Setup a deny/allow
    Order Deny,Allow
    # Deny from everyone
    Deny from all
    # except if either of these are satisfied
    Satisfy any
    # 1. a valid authenticated user
    Require valid-user
    # or 2. the "allow" var is set
    Allow from env=allow
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess mod_rewrite rules:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !(^GET|^POST|^HEAD)
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/img|/js|/css|/fonts)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php
```

**Edit 1** - based on the comments I also tried: `SetEnv allow true` and `SetEnv allow 1` to remove the doubt of whether it's the URL and it still asks for the basic auth password, so it may not be related to the URL afterall.

**Edit 2** - Adding the entire .htaccess to make sure I'm not missing something else:

```
php_value max_input_vars 4000

RewriteEngine on

# Disallow other HTTP verbs such as PUT and DELETE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !(^GET|^POST|^HEAD)
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/img|/js|/css|/fonts|/twig|/pdf|/vendors|/server-status)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json font/woff font/otf font/eot font/ttf
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType font/eot "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, proxy-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(js|css|ttf|eot|otf|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, proxy-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

**Edit 3** - Sorry, should have mentioned that we're stuck on Apache 2.2 for now.

Comment: _“guessing but didn't know how to 100% confirm this.”_ - easy, use `SetEnv` instead of `SetEnvIf`, to set the variable in any case, independent of the request URI, and see if your deny/require/allow setup allows you access without credentials then. If it does, then you know the `SetEnvIf` did not work as desired, and if it doesn’t, then you know the error is in the rest of that setup.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! The plot thickens.. I just tried `SetEnv allow true` and `SetEnv allow 1` and it still asks for a password.

Comment: Your `auth` code looks ok and it should work as is. Are there any other rules or directives in your htaccess? Also try clearing your browser cache and try restarting your server to see if that helps.

Comment: I'll update the question with my entire .htaccess, but couldn't see anything else relevant. And I've cleared cache and restarted the server, but the same issue still happens. Testing it locally now using docker and have fully rebuilt the containers.

Answer (score 3):

Using Apache 2.4+ you can use `<If>` expression to disable auth or use `allow from all` directive for a URI using `THE_REQUEST` variable. `THE_REQUEST` represents original request sent to Apache and it doesn't get updated in the context of a single request:

```sh
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwords/sub.ourdomain.co.uk
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
Order   deny,allow
Deny from  all

<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ /webhook/">
Satisfy any
Allow from all
</If>

# your current mod_rewrite rules can appear below this line:
DirectoryIndex boot.php
RewriteEngine on

# Disallow other HTTP verbs such as PUT and DELETE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule ^ - [R=405,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/img|/js|/css|/fonts|/twig|/pdf|/vendors|/server-status)
RewriteRule ^ boot.php [L]
```

---

**Update:** Here is a **workaround solution that works on Apache 2.2 using `<FilesMatch>` directive**:

```sh
DirectoryIndex boot.php
RewriteEngine on

# Disallow other HTTP verbs such as PUT and DELETE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule ^ - [R=405,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/img|/js|/css|/fonts|/twig|/pdf|/vendors|/server-status)
RewriteRule ^ boot.php [L]

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/webhook/ allow

<FilesMatch "^(?!boot\.php$).*$">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Restricted Content"
   AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwords/sub.ourdomain.co.uk
   Require valid-user
   Order   Deny,Allow
   Deny from  all
   Allow from env=allow
   Satisfy any
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're stuck on 2.2 right now. Plans to upgrade are out of my control (but have voiced that we should!). Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: So we'd need to put this in the vhost config instead of using .htaccess? Not sure I fully follow. Ideally wanted to keep the Rewrite conditions in htaccess, and the Basic Auth in the vhost. Guess this is impossible?

Comment: We wanted to avoid using htaccess because that's in our application (commited to git) and shared between all environments - so we'd have to do some funky stuff during deployment to say "if env == this, use this htaccess file, otherwise use this one". Only a couple of environments need to have this basic auth, which is why it works great being able to just add it to those virtualhosts which need it.

Comment: This answer will work same way if it is included in vhost config. Of course that will require restart every time you make a change. Test this in your vhost config and let me know how it goes. btw you should remove `.htaccess` tag from question if you don't want to use it there.

Comment: Just getting a "bad request" response on everything apart from the root of our site with it in the vhost config. We're just going to turn off Basic Auth and rely on other authentication methods in the application. Have ran out of time so can't look into it anymore for a while :( Will maybe come back to it someday in my spare time and crack it..

Comment: You should check your Apache error.log for the reason of bad request. Both code blocks have been tested on my local Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Caution with @anubhava's reply – it contains a security problem!

`<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ /webhook/">` only checks wether the request *contains* the string "/webhook/". So by adding `?uselessParameter=/webhook/` to your requests, you can access all the private resources that should be password protected!

You could match the beginning of the `THE_REQUEST` variable, using the `^` character. But that means your Regex also has to include the HTTP verb.

```xml
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ ^GET /webhook/">
```

Sadly, no Apache parameter seems to contain only the actual URI or the actual path – at least I couldn't find one.